# Is there an embedded operating system without a kernel heap?

Tags: memory, operating-system, embedded, kernel, heap-memory

AFAIK, kernels usually manage their own heap memory to dynamically allocate kernel objects, e.g., `kmalloc` in Linux (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.0/core-api/memory-allocation.html). But some embedded devices have very scarce memory, and the use of heap is discouraged. I'm wondering whether there is an embedded operating system without a kernel heap, and I'd like to know some example if there's any.

I tried to search on Google but I couldn't find any. I'm not an OS expert, and I don't think I know the correct keyword to search for.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "operating system".  Most RTOS kernels either do not use or create a heap, or it's use is optional.  But such RTOSes are hardly comparable to Linux.  In real-time systems, scarcity of memory is not the primary issue with heap usage, but rather deterministic behaviour and timing.

Comment: Why do you need an OS to begin with? If heap allocation shouldn't be used, then pretty much all-things-Linux/POSIX shouldn't be used either. A RTOS is suitable for structuring large, complex programs with multiple things going on at once. Otherwise, "bare metal" works just fine up to a certain point of complexity.